# Using an URLClassLoader inside Jetty

Tags: java, maven, jetty, wicket

I am developing a wicket application which is running on jetty. My application should be able to load plugins from jar-files.
Thus I created a `URLClassLoader` which should load the plugin classes.

As a standard Java-application everything works, but when I want to load plugins on the server I get following errors: http://pastebin.com/e2JRAYTr

The `Module` interface that can not be found is defined in another project, but if I output the class-name in Wickets `init()` method like this

```
System.out.println(Module.class.getName())`
```

I get no error. So I think the other project is loaded correctly by Maven but there are issues with my custom jar-classloader.

The classloaders constructor where the action happens looks like this:

```
public WorkableLoader(final File jarFile) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException {
    final URL[] urls = new URL[] { jarFile.toURI().toURL() };
    classLoader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    final Class<?> cls = loadWorkableClass(jarFile);
    workable = (Workable) cls.newInstance();
}

private Class<?> loadWorkableClass(final File jar) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
    try (final JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(jar)) {
        final Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntries = jarFile.entries();

        while (jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
            final JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntries.nextElement();

            if (isClassFile(jarEntry.getName())) {
                final String className = jarEntry.getName().replace("/", ".").replace(".class", "");
                final Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass(className);

                for (final Class<?> iface : cls.getInterfaces()) {
                    if (iface.equals(Module.class) || iface.equals(Bundle.class)) {
                        return cls;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    throw new ClassNotFoundException("Es konnte keine Workable-Klasse gefunden werden.");
}
```

The method `isClass()` just checks if the file ends with `.class`.
The last error of my code is `at com.siemens.importer.workables.WorkableLoader.loadWorkableClass(WorkableLoader.java:137)`. Line 137 is the line
`final Class<?> cls = classLoader.loadClass(className);` of the `loadWorkableClass()` method. So how can I load classes with a custom classloader on a
jetty server?

Sorry for the huge output and thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you use a new URLClassLoader per plugin strategy and you've mentioned that the definition of the `Module` interface is also within an own plugin. When you try to load a new plugin, which depends on the `Module` interface, the newly created URLClassLoader (as of the before mentioned strategy) does not have access to the loaded interface definition. In that case you need to parent the newly created classloader to the classloader which loaded the `Module` interface class.

Comment: The Module interface is in the classpath and managed by Maven.

Comment: Sorry, I missread and thought you've loaded it as a plugin ... you could try to parent the URLClassloader to the classloader which loaded your WorkableLoader. It seems that URLClassLoader has problems with the default parent class laoder, so better try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader%28java.net.URL[],%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29

Comment: This was the problem. I had to use the classloader of the WebApplication class. Now it is working. If you write your comments as an answer, I can mark it accepted.